# android universal image loader not working correctly

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter, universal-image-loader

I have a cursor adapter whose bindView is as follows:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
...
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);

    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheOnDisk(true).cacheInMemory(true)
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_contact_picture).showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_contact_picture)
                .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
                .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300)).build();

    imageLoader.displayImage(url, imageView, options);
...
}
```

The problem I'm getting is:

When I scroll through the listview, an item's imageview image gets displayed in some another item's imageview. Why does this happen?

Is internal recycling of listview items causing a problem?

Answer (score 0):

As you say,the problem maybe because of the recycler mechanism of listview,you should use ViewHolder to hold your item view for performance optimization and solve wrong position problem like yours.